# Почему добавление сигнала в pyqtSignal не распространяется на все экземпляры?

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

```
import sys
import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import  QThread, Qt, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot


class Thr(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self,*a,**r):
        super().__init__(*a,**r)

    temp=0
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.signal.emit(self.temp)
            self.temp+=1
            
            
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(label)

dial = QtWidgets.QDial()
dial2 = QtWidgets.QDial()
layout.addWidget(dial)
layout.addWidget(dial2)

thr1=Thr(label)
thr2=Thr(label)
thr1.signal.connect(dial.setValue)
thr2.signal.connect(dial2.setValue)
thr1.start()

label.resize(500, 500)
label.show()
app.exec_()
```

Я не понимаю, почему когда мы в разных Qt-тредах добавляем в `pyqtSignal` какой то слот, он привязывается к конкретному классу QThread. Ведь в данном примере `signal = pyqtSignal(int)` является статическим полем и добавление какого то слота будет распространяться на все классы `QThread`, и вызов `emit` в любом экземпляре класса `Thr` должен распространяться на все подключенные слоты к `pyqtSignal` всех эксземпляров. В данном примере когда мы добавляем в 2 экземпляра `Thr` сигналы для`setValue`и не запускаем второй поток, то второй `QDial` не вращается.

Answer (score 1):

Да, в данном примере если вы НЕ запускаете ВТОРОЙ поток `thr2.start()`, то второй `QDial` не вращается.

Вы устанавливаете соединение, при котором вы можете получить доступ к обоим объектам (отправителю и получателю).

```
thr2.signal.connect(dial2.setValue)
```

Слот (`dial2.setValue`) вызывается немедленно, 
когда сигнал is emitted (`self.signal.emit(self.temp)`).

Т.е. надо чтобы в методе `run()`, ДЛЯ ВТОРОГО ПОТОКА, выполнялось
`self.signal.emit(self.temp)`:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        self.msleep(100)
        self.signal.emit(self.temp)                     # !!!
        self.temp += 1
```

Но метод `run()`, ДЛЯ ВТОРОГО ПОТОКА, начнет выполняться только после
`thr2.start()`.

> void QThread::[**start**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#start)(QThread::Priority priority = InheritPriority)
>
> Начинает выполнение потока с вызова [**run()**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run).

Вот и получам:

- `thr2.start()` не сделали;
- выполнение ВТОРОГО потока, вызов `run()` не происходит;
- `self.signal.emit(self.temp)` не выполняется;
- `thr2.signal.connect(dial2.setValue)` не срабатывает.

Comment: Но тема вопроса не раскрыта. Сигнал один для всех экземпляров? -Да, так как он является статическим членом. Тогда любое присоединение слота к сигналу в любом экземпляре будет относиться к одному pyqtSignal. По этому любой вызов emit для этого сигнала В ЛЮБОМ ЭКЗЕМПЛЯРЕ должен кидать сигналы во все слоты всех экземпляров.

Comment: @Barracudach где вы прочитали о том что утверждаете уже второй раз и в комментариях и теле вопроса ? И подскажите, пожалуйста, с какой целью вы делаете `thr2=Thr(label)` ?

Comment: Я походу просто не знаю как работают статические поля в Python) Я думал что тут статические поля одни на все экземпляры

Comment: @Barracudach я не знаю, что вы вкладываете в понятие  `статические поля`. Свяжите два сигнала и добавьте перед строкой `thr1.start()`  строку `thr1.signal.connect(thr2.signal)` и проверьте что у вас получится.